# Java equals("[a-zA-Z]+") always false

Tags: java

so, I'm trying to create something that checks kinderCode (String) on only containing letters. If it does contain a character that is not a letter, it needs to ask the user to supply a new value for kinderCode which is then again checked. The issue here is that the while loop is never left. The condition always returns false.

```
kinderCode = input.next();       
while (!(kinderCode.equals("[a-zA-Z]+"))) {
     System.out.println("Foute ingave! Kindercode?");
     kinderCode = input.next();
}
```

Comment: `equals` doesn't use a regex, it compares two plain strings.

Comment: The `String.equals` method does not use a regular expression so this is expected. Try `String.matches` instead

Comment: Would this accept things like ñ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.matches()`

```
while (!(kinderCode.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))) {

// rest of the code 
}
```

> `matches(String regex)`
>
> Tells whether or not this string matches the given  regular expression

The `.equals()` is used to compare *equality* of Strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(kinderCode);
 if (matcher.find()){
        return true;
   }
 return false;
```

Use assertTrue or assertFalse for condition matching as code ethics.